# Realtime Scoring

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am working on creating a realtime scoring site. I've ran into a brick wall about how I should display my games scoreboard on one page. I want to use `jquery/javascript` to pull data from a `JSON` file and create multiple tables from it.

Here is the content of my `JSON` file.

```
{"basketball_scores":[
    ["basket001","15","12","7","34","10","12","4","26"],
    ["basket002","10","15","5","30","5","10","5","20"],
    ["basket003","3","4","2","9","4","6","10","20"],
    ["basket004","2","6","2","10","5","3","4","12"]
]}
```

I want to be able to create 4 tables that auto populate rows and column from each game.

Here is how I would like to display it:

```
matchup  half1  half2  ot  final 
home     15     12     7   34 
away     10     12     4   26
```

That would be one table. I would like to continue this for the rest of the field.

The number of game is unknown i've just used 4 as an example.

Comment: What exactly do you need from us?

Comment: Ok, let me try to explain this a bit better. I want to assign values from the json file to div tags which then I can use to plug in to tables that are auto generated.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ http://php.net/manual/en/index.php http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html

Comment: $.getJSON('loadjson.php', function(data) {
        var table = '<table>'; /* loop over each object in the array to create rows*/
        $.each(data, function(index, item) { /* add to html string started above*/
            table += '<tr><td>' + item.team + '</td><td>' + item.mvp + '</td></tr>';
        });
        table += '</table>'; /* insert the html string*/
        $("#content").html(table);
    });

I've tried to used this example it puts all the game content onto one table. How can I separate each game?

Comment: In the code you just posted there is a comment "loop over each object in the array to create rows" - for your requirement you just have to change that code to "loop over each object in the array to create _tables_ (with your desired format)". Concatenating strings of html will still work, you just have to adapt it.

Comment: the downvotes on your question is just to encourage you to ask a more specific question. looking at your 2nd comment, it looks like you are pretty familiar with both html and jquery. think the only thing you are missing is a small tweak to your algorithm; you need 2 loops: one to iterate through each game data record (rows), one to iterate through the details of the game (columns)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to query you're backend for the `JSON` data (that you want), and you can update it, using the `success` function in `jquery.ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax polling is not realtime. Realtime is when something changes in you database, push that data into website, web page or whatever.

1. some script receives new data
2. you insert that data into db
3. you push that data into page

you need [Strophe library](http://strophe.im) for this and some [php XMPP class](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/) if you are using php. Every other language also have libraries for manipulating xmpp messages.

Of course this is easier said then done. [This is the boo](http://professionalxmpp.com/)k on this metter.
If you are looking for finished solution then skip all that I said.