# Order of application communication in a live score MEAN stack app

Tags: mongodb, socket.io, mean-stack

I want to create a live score web app using the MEAN stack where multiple concurrent users are able to visit the site without any authentication and get scores for up to 6 different sports.

Data within the system can be updated via RESTful requests to a third-party API that I found on the internet.

I understand that socket.io allows for concurrent users/ clients to connect to the application but I'm a little confused as to how the structure and the order of data transfer should look like in this web app.

Is the order something like.. ?:

- User goes onto the site
- User selects Football from a dropdown menu
- Web application sends request to the API
- Response is saved in a mongo DB
- Web application queries the DB
- Web application updates latest score on the website

This seems incorrect to me?
I just want to know what would be the most efficient way of getting the scores from the API then displaying it to the users all in real time.

I read in another stack overflow question that:

"
Realtime is when something changes in you database, push that data into website, web page or whatever.

- some script receives new data
- you insert that data into db
- you push that data into page
  " [Realtime Scoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696787/realtime-scoring)

How would this 'script' work? Do I have to poll the API on every tick and update the database using that? Seems very 'expensive'

Comment: Hey, we're [discussing this question in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42352355#42352355).